# How do I automatically log a fatal error to a file?

Tags: android

I have an app that crashes at random times when I don't have a computer nearby to view logcat. Therefore I want to write the reason for a fatal error / every error to a file on my phone that I can read later to debug. I tried using try catch, but I am looking for a complete solution, like a command I enter once and it captures every crash and saves it, like an observer above the code respectively a kind of virtual box.

Which command helps me here?

Answer (score 1):

Using a file for this is a bad idea - Not only do you possible have to worry about extra permissions but you also have to write a fair amount of code.

There are many libraries out there to catch Exceptions and log them for you.

Furthermore in a live environment this won't work at catching bugs since you can't ask users to send them a log file.

I use Fabric (Firebase)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Answer (score 0):

I to wanted something similar, the solution that I came up with that works a bit was a Debug Log activity in the app that reads the `logcat` output in to a `TextView`.

I then Start this activity from a Menu Item or Button to show previous crashes.

Normally Android Studio Logcat window is just opening a remote shell on to the device with ADB and running the `logcat` command on the Android Device.

This method runs the `logcat` command on the Device itself without the need of a remote shell, but you need some Java code in your app to do this.

(This Extra Activity has to be in the Same App as you only have permission to see you own App's `logcat`)

(This does not always seem to pick up always all Log output but it does pickup crashes)

**NOTE**
The `try` and `catch` in this example code has nothing to do with trying to catch the errors Alex is Hunting as some people thought but to catch a possible error in the logcat display code. The logcat text shown by this Activity will show stack traces of those errors Alex is hunting.

This could then be run after restarting the app.

Code to do this is (Note you need to replace the "YOUR_APPS_TAG" with the Log TAG used by your app) See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat for the filter specs

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DebugLogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_debug_log);

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -D -v long " + "YOUR_APPS_TAG" + ":V *:E");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line );
                log.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.debugLog);
            tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            tv.setTextIsSelectable(true);
            tv.setText(log.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (BuildConfig.LOG) {
                Log.e("YOUR_APPS_TAG", "DebugLogActivity:onCreate:" + e.toString() + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The xml (actvitiy_debug_log.xml) for this extra activity

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".debuglogActivity">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/debugLog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Example ScreenShot of running Activity after a crash
[image]

You can then copy and paste the text out and send it to yourself or just read it in the app.

Comment: @m0skit0 You miss understand the code the `try` and `catch` in the example code given are to catch errors in the code that displays `logcat` in the application itself instead of Android Studio. It is not trying to `catch` the errors Alex is looking for. The `logcat` output displayed by this extra activity will show stack traces like the `Logcat` Window in Android Studio

Comment: @m0skit0 Again you miss understand the question, Alex Says "Therefore I want to write the reason for a fatal error / every error to a file on my phone" - This is already done by the OS, you just need to read the files on the phone. Alex's question was "Which command helps me here?" - my answer is `logcat` command but run locally on Device

Comment: Wrong. What he wants is to capture ALL exceptions independently on where they happen (which you're not doing), and write them somewhere so he can access them later (which you're also not doing).

Comment: It is true that my solution does not catch crashes in un-related applications but neither does instrumenting your app with Firebase Crashlytics but you are wrong the OS is writing them to somewhere he can access them later, my code shows him how to access it later (If you notice the crash in my screen shot is dated the 15th of Oct when the screen shot was taken over a month later). You can even increase the log size in the developer menus to store them for even longer.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler) or even better, [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android).